# nslookup: *** Can't find server name

Tags: windows-xp, dns, nslookup

I am using `nslookup` command line tool from Windows XP but i can't see the IP of the DNS Server i am conducting. I am getting the message:

```
*** Can't find server name for address 192.168.1.1: Non-existent domain
*** Default servers are not available
```

How can i fix that?

Comment: Same question is on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330395/dns-problem-nslookup-works-ping-doesnt

Comment: @DiamondPlus: not necessarily. While the question you mentioned is about a DNS server setup in a home network, I have the same problem if I do `nslookup google.com` (with or without trailing dot). My router does the DNS forwarding and works fine (I can ping and browse `google.com`), but the error messages mentioned in the question are still there.